# boost::variant move semantics when use boost::apply_visitor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, boost-variant, apply-visitor

When I tried to build one AST from another ([constant folding](http://pastebin.com/P4Gb9DX0)), I noticed, that there is unnecessary copy-construction at the time of the call the visitor. But the move-construction should be there, if we talk about the C++11/C++1y.

Are there any insurmountable difficulties to create the version of visitor/multivisitor, that supports universal references properly?

Comment: No, there are no insurmountable problems. Boost.Variant was designed long before C++11, and so does not have support for such things. I imagine that the maintainer would appreciate a patch to add support (possibly using Boost.Move to provide C++03 emulation).

Comment: @Mankarse I sure, that is not simple matter to add such support. Needs all the experience of Maintainer, to do no harm.

Comment: Certainly, it would probably be much easier to write an entirely new variant class from scratch than to add support to Boost.Variant (while maintaining compatibility with and support for older compilers). Even so, the problem is with the implementation of Boost.Variant, rather than with the concept of a variant class in C++, or even with the high level interface exposed by Boost.Variant.

Comment: I found the workaround: is to use static visitor in manner like `struct A : boost::static_visitor< void > { result_type operator () (int & x) { ... = std::move(x); } };`. I.e. with non-const reference parametres in functor signature.